# « Champagniser » et « Champaniser » : prononciation selon le sexe du locuteur ?

Tags: prononciation, orthographe, phonétique, genre-biologique

Dans *Tintin en Amérique* :

> Voici les évènements de la journée d’hier, d’après le professeur W.R.
>   Law, [...] 150 gallons d’eau de Javel *champagnisée* ont été saisis
>   par la police : le Coroner et 29 policiers sont à l’hôpital…
>
> [ *Tintin en Amérique* (1932), Hergé, éd. Casterman, coll. Tintin,
>   1945, t. 3, p. 36 ]

On trouve à « [*champagniser*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/champagniser) » un commentaire sur la *graphie* et la *prononciation* :

> Champagniser, verbe trans. Préparer des vins blancs de crus divers
>   selon la méthode champenoise (cf. Ali-Bab, *Gastr. pratique*, 1907, p.
>   154). *Vins de Touraine champanisés [sic]* (A. Daudet, *Immortel*,
>   1888, p. 242).− [ʃ ɑ ̃paɳize]. La majorité des dict., surtout à partir de 
>   *Guérin* 1892, enregistrent *champagniser*. *Besch.* 1845 écrit uniquement
>   *champaniser*. Cette forme est mentionnée ds *Lar. 19e, Nouv. Lar. ill.,
>   Littré*. Elle est empl. comme vedette à côté de *champagniser* ds *Quillet*
>   1965. Cette graph. traduit une altération dans la prononc. de 
>   l'articulation de [ɳ]. La nasale [ɳ] est altérée de l'a. fr. en
>   passant par le m. fr. jusqu'au début du xviii<sup>e</sup>s. On entendait ainsi à
>   **Paris** [ano] à la place de [aɳo]. Cf. *Bourc.-Bourc.* 1967, § 198. En
>   outre, G. Straka (*Qq. obs.
>   phonét. sur le lang. des femmes* ds *Orbis*, 1952, t. 1, no2, pp.
>   340-345) fait la rem. suiv. au sujet de l'instabilité de [ɳ] qui est
>   normalement occlusive et palatale : ,,Elle est tantôt palatale, tantôt
>   vélaire, et quand elle est palatale, tantôt la pointe de la langue
>   s'infléchit derrière les incisives inférieures (ce qui est normal),
>   tantôt elle s'appuie contre les alvéoles et le palais dur; on peut
>   encore observer, à côté de l'articulation occlusive de l'ɳ, une
>   articulation plus ou moins relâchée et constrictive. Nous avons
>   attribué l'instabilité de cette consonne au fait qu'en tant que
>   palatale, elle se trouve actuellement **isolée** dans le système
>   phonétique du français.`` G. Straka (ibid.) souligne que la consonne
>   est plus souvent **atteinte** chez les femmes que chez les hommes, ce
>   qu'il explique par l'énergie articulatoire que requiert la prononc. de
>   cette consonne, énergie qui est **moins forte** chez les femmes que
>   chez les hommes. − 1<sup>res</sup> attest. 1839 (Boiste d'apr. *Lar. Lang. fr.*),
>   av. 1845 *champaniser* (*Dict. du comm.* ds Besch. *Suppl.*), 1866
>   *champagniser* (*Lar.* 19e); de champagne<sup>2</sup>, suff. -iser*.
>
> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé* (TLFi) - extrait de
>   « [*champagniser*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/champagniser) » ]

---

1. Sommairement, pourquoi l'ɳ se trouve-t-elle « *isolée dans le système phonétique du français* » ?
2. Qu'entend-on par « *atteinte* » dans le contexte de la prononciation de la consonne ?
3. Est-il de notoriété dans le domaine qu'il y ait une « *énergie articulatoire* » différente entre la femme et l'homme; est-ce que ça signifierait qu'on puisse attribuer ici historiquement la présence des deux graphies à une prononciation qui illustre cette différence, celle-ci disant davantage « *champaniser* » et celui-là, « *champagniser* »; quel est le lien le cas échéant entre ceci et la référence à Paris jusqu'au début du XVIII<sup>e</sup> ?

Comment: Question intéressante mais peut-être simplement l'évolution de la langue. Cela ressemble beaucoup au cas du féminin [« maligne »](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/maligne), qui se prononce normalement `/ma.liɲ/` mais populairement `/ma.lin/`. La [graphie « maline » est encore considérée incorrecte](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/maline#Forme_d.E2.80.99adjectif) dans cet usage, mais pour combien de temps ? On pourrait se demander si les raisons de cette évolution sont les mêmes que pour ton exemple.

Comment: @Chop oui je pense que c'est l'évolution de la langue par la loi du moindre effort. Le problème est dans dans le cas de "maligne" => "maline", le mot existe déjà, ce qui est plus gênant que pour "champagne"...

Comment: @Random Cela est-il vraiment gênant ? Des mots peuvent adopter de nouvelles significations au fil du temps, par extension de sens existants ou d'une autre façon, d'où la multiplicité de leurs définitions. Mais oui, nous (humains) sommes partisans du moindre effort. Qui parle encore de « cinématographe » ou de « photographie » ? « Cinéma » (voire « ciné ») et « photo » sont bien plus courants. Si je comprends l'aspect pratique (moi-même coupable), je me demande où cela conduira notre langue. Une légère modification de prononciation me semble peu à côté de l'abandon de syllabes entières.

Comment: Cependant, le propre d'une langue vivante est d'évoluer. :)

Comment: Je ne connais pas le domaine. Je [lis](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_occlusive_nasale_r%C3%A9troflexe_vois%C3%A9e) que le français ne possède pas le [ɳ] (Consonne occlusive nasale rétroflexe voisée). Je ne comprends pas pourquoi on montre cette prononciation dans _champagniser_ alors que ça semble plutôt correspondre à [ɲ], la [consonne nasale palatale](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_nasale_palatale); je note aussi [ŋ] [consonne occlusive nasale vélaire voisée](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_occlusive_nasale_v%C3%A9laire_vois%C3%A9e). Je comprends que vélaire, palatale...

Comment: ... et rétroflexe ont trait à l'utilisation du palais dans la prononciation. Mais je suis incapable de faire les liens qui s'imposent ici avec le mot en question en regardant quelque chose comme [ceci](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononciation_du_fran%C3%A7ais) ou [ceci](http://venus.unive.it/canipa/pdf/HPr_04_French_fr.pdf). J'ai très peu d'intérêt pour l'évolution de la graphie ou de l'orthographe du mot comme tel; c'est un prétexte pour illustrer deux prononciations et amener la différence biologique, que j'aimerais voir qualifiée et quantifiée. Je veux savoir si on peut l'étayer. Merci.

Answer (score 2):

1. Isolé car pour le prononcer, on doit coller la langue contre le palais, ce qui semble en faire un phonème isolé des autres.
2. **Atteinte** dans le sens "les femmes font plus souvent l'effort de la prononcer", elles **arrivent** plus souvent à la prononcer. On parle d'**atteindre** les aigus quand on chante par exemple, car cela demande un effort, et tout le monde ne peut pas le faire.
3. Cela demande clairement un effort supplémentaire de prononcer [**ɳ**] comparé à [**ni**], alors qu'en parlant vite, les deux prononciation sont très similaires. Après, concernant la différence homme/femme, je ne suis pas compétant pour argumenter.

Comment: Merci! Cependant, peut-on confirmer pour 2. Plus souvent atteinte chez la femme vs. l'énergie moins forte. Ce dernier élément semble incompatible avec l'atteinte. Quand on dit la consonne, ne parle-t-on pas de la principale, ɳ. Donc je lis "atteinte" comme "non-intègre"; je veux savoir s'il y a une acception particulière en linguistique. Le sexe du locuteur est central dans le sens où c'est le première fois de ma vie où je suis exposé à l'idée d'une différence entre l'homme et la femme qui aurait un impact quantifiable et observable sur la prononciation des mots, ce qui motive la Q. Merci!

Comment: Le son dont il est question ici est un ɲ (nasale palatale) et pas un ɳ (nasale rétroflexe). En pratique, ce phonème est prononcé nᴶ (nasale palatalisée) pour la plupart des français. Il existe un contraste entre /nᴶ/ et /nj/ qui est à l'œuvre dans la différence entre les verbes MANIER et MAGNER prononcés de façon semblable à l'infinitif mais avec des conjugaisons différentes liées à leur radicaux distincts : /manj/ vs /manᴶ/.